# To Modify the .htaccess for 301 Redirect with Asp.net on the fly (Dynamically)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cpanel

I make changes using Cpanel / Redirect manager of a Site.

Based on the Changes made on Cpanel for URL redirection, i.e. Say Old Url -> Current Url, I want to modify the .htaccess file dynamically. How do I achieve this using Asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do URL redirection in ASP.NET. See more information about this topic. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite.

Comment: No, i want it with .htaccess, and whenever i change in Admin panel of Redirect manager, i.e Old Url= xyz  New Url= abc. Hence, it will update the ,.htaccess dynamically.